# how to using regex to delete some data in python after beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex

i am using the beautifulsoup to scrape the HTML data.

My issue is the output displays some information i donot want to see,
so, i tried to use regex to delete that information,

however, not good at regex, so i put my script here and the output i want,
hope anyone can help me.

regards

my outputs now shows like:

```
<title>Music Games DVDs at JB Hi-Fi Australia</title>
Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â 
                        <span class="SKU">MD528X/A</span>
Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (White) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â 
                             <span class="SKU">MD531X/A</span>
Apple iPad mini 32GB Wi-Fi (Black) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â 
                        <span class="SKU">MD529X/A</span>
```

however, i only want it show like:

```
JB Hi-Fi Australia

Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black)

Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (White)
```

the following is my script

```
url1="http://www.jbhifionline.com.au/support.aspx?post=1&results=10&q=ipad+mini&source=all&bnSearch.x=0&bnSearch.y=0"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())


#website source site name : <title>Music Games DVDs at JB   Hi-FiAustralia</title>
sitename1=soup.html.head.title
print sitename1     ##issue here!!output shows <title>....</title>

#website source name:<td class="check_title">Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black)   [Pick-up In-store Only]<span class="SKU$`
productname1=soup.findAll('td',{'class':'check_title'})
for eachproductname1 in productname1:

    print  eachproductname1.renderContents().replace("^<span>","")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each in productname1:
x = each.contents[0].strip()
    x = re.sub(r'\[[\w\s-]*\][\xc2]',"",x)
    print x
```

Output:

```
 Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black) 
 Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (White) 
 Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi + Cellular (Black)
```

I hope this helps. I had to answer again, as this is complete solution.

Comment: that's worked~ real help me. i think i need to restudy the regex again.thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
replace("<.+?>|\[.+?\]", "")
```

Comment: try this one "<.+>|\[.+\]"

Comment: sorry, i tried many times, still not figure out, anyway,thanks,good night~

Answer (score 0):

For the title, it should be easy enough to strip the  and  tags. Then you are left with stripping the "Music Games DVDs at " out of the title... is that constant text? Since this pertains to a fixed website that you're scraping, why not just hard code the title information you want: **JB Hi-Fi Australia**? That would seem to be a lot easier than trying to trim down the string you receive.

For a given product line, are you looking to strip off the [ and everything after? That should be easy enough with regex. Are we looking at a line at a time, so

> Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â

is separate from

> ```
>              <span class="SKU">MD528X/A</span>
> ```

? For the first, something like

```
eachproductname1.renderContents().replace("\[.*$","")
```

and for the second (get rid of the whole line), something like

```
eachproductname1.renderContents().replace("^[ \t]*<.*$","")
```

Not being experienced in Python and its flavor of regular expressions, I can't guarantee that will work straight out of the box. You may have to play around a bit with that code. As suggested in the previous answer, you might be able to combine the two into a single egrep expression.

Comment: firstly, thanks for reply. for you code, i tired similar code before, only delete the </span> part. and i tried you code, sorry, not work. in addition, the reason why i am not type the title because i need to scrape several webpage and insert in one database, the output need to show the different sitename, so i think type it is not a good idea. anyway,thanks a lot~

Comment: My point about `<title>Music Games DVDs at JB Hi-Fi Australia</title>` is that you have no control over their title. 1) they could change it tomorrow to **JB Hi-Fi's Music, Games, and DVDS**. 2) Different stores could have different title layouts, e.g., `DVDs, Music, and Games at Crazy Eddie's Emporium`. If you know that you're scraping the "JB Hi_Fi Australia" website (because you have to provide the URL anyway), I would think it a lot easier to simply hard code the name, than to try to extract the business name from the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
for eachproductname1 in productname1:
    print  eachproductname1.contents[0].strip()
```

Output : (You can modify this in a way you want, I think that should be easy from this point)

```
Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (Black) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â
Apple iPad mini 16GB Wi-Fi (White) [Pick-up In-store Only]Â
```

Comment: for each in productname1:
 x = each.contents[0].strip()
        x = re.sub(r'\[[\w\s-]*\][\xc2]',"",x)
        print x